# Execute shell waits before running

Tags: jenkins

I'm in the process of migrating our build server from a local machine to a virtual one on ec2. I've got everything working, but I've noticed that when I specify something to run in the shell, it hangs for around 30 seconds or so before actually running the commands specified.

So for example, the first thing I do is call `env` to print out all the environment variables to aid troubleshooting:

[image]

If I watch the console output, I will get this line, followed by the spinner:

`$ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8414496369434804156.sh`

About 30 seconds later I will get the list of environment variables printed to the console.

During the time the spinner is present without any output, I can navigate to `C:\Windows\TEMP\` and open `hudson8414496369434804156.sh` to confirm the file is there with the contents of `env`. So I can only conclude it's just not invoking the shell while it is sat there...doing something.

This isn't a one off, it does it every time I use the `Execute shell` option under `Build`. The next thing I do is run a `git clone` command also via `Execute shell`, and it behaves exactly the same.

Why is it taking so long to run the shell commands, and how can I stop this, or reduce the waiting period?

I don't believe it is a performance related issues with the machines, as the new one has better specification:

Old machine: `Pentium Dual-Core E5400 2.7GHz`, `4GB RAM`, `300GB HDD`, `Windows 8 Pro`.

New machine: `Xeon E5-2670 v2 2.5GHz`, `4GB RAM`, `300GB HDD`, `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

The old version of Jenkins where I didn't have this issue was `1.517`, and the new version is `1.613`. In the `System Information`, the `java.runtime.version` is `1.7.0_21-b11` for the old, and `1.8.0_20-b26` for the new. Going to Window's  control panel, this shows as Java 7 Update 17 (x64) and Java 8 Update 45 (x64), respectively.

Any ideas? My Google-fu has failed. Cheers.

Edit 1:

To answer [Slav's questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247092/execute-shell-waits-before-running#comment48621453_30247092): Running `sh --version` in `cmd` returns immediately with `GNU bash, version 3.1.23(6)-release (i686-pc-msys) Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` There's no delay.

Creating a dummy `.sh` file in my desktop folder, only with the contents `env`, and then running it in the `cmd` with `sh -xe dummy.sh` also returns immediately, printing out all the environment variables.

Comment: It's very weird that you have a Windows machine, yet you are calling "Execute Shell" .  `sh` is not native to Windows. What happens when you open `cmd` and just type `sh --version` there? Any delays? Try creating a dummy `.sh` file, and opening that through `cmd` with `sh -xe c:\path\to\file.sh`

Comment: @Slav Thanks for your suggestions. It's a Windows machine as I'm using `MSBuild` for a .NET application, but I'm more familiar with unix commands. Anyway, I've updated my question to answer your questions, but the short answer is they all return immediately.